# Limit the time users use the software

Tags: python, django

I have an app program by Python 3 and I want to limited the time users use this app(EX: 4 hours a day).

**My idea:**

- Count and write the time to the file which is encrypted and hidden, check the time when open (but users can delete this file(intentionally or by an antivirus program,...))
- Count the time users use and send it to my Django website. When users open app, it check out time allowed to use remaining in my web. I want when the user closes the app, it will send to my site information then the *check_time*(html or something) page will display numbers, which is the time remaining for the next use.

If the time is up, notify the user and close the app.

It is possible? Is there any other way? Please give me a suggestion.

**Edit:**

- To check the time, I will use [time.is](https://time.is), and to use this app the user must be connected to a network, which prevent users from changing system time.
- The timer  will start when user click on the start button and stop when them click stop button.

Comment: Server-side validation is the only thing that has any shot at being foolproof.  Remember that the user can (a) change their system clock (b) turn off their network -- if you want the check to be really strict, the program should refuse to start until it's gotten a server response telling it how much more time it has left in the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write data to a local file in encrypted format. This way the encryption function will be a signature which will allow your application to understand that the recording was made by it.

You can also add a rule that if the file storing the remaining time is deleted, the time is over and the user has to wait for your application to resume it.

If you gonna do that, you better query time from free network resourse, so user will not be able to affect it by changing system time.

Comment: Thank you about the answer, I will try the rule :D.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cookie/decorator combination or db/decorator combination.

For a simple example of the former:

decorator.py

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def time_decorator(func):
    '''
    The decorator checks whether the time a user has s[ent logged in

    Ensure that cookies are enabled in client borwser

    '''
    def check_time(request):
        if "login_time" in request.session:
            if (timezone.now() - request.session["login_time"])> timedelta(hours=4)     
                ### Redirect to a page that informs the user that their time is up
                return redirect("login_timeout_url")
        else:
            ### Set login time cookie
            request.session['login_time'] = timezone.now()

            
        return func(request)
    return check_time
```

views.py

```
from .decorator import time_decorator

@time_decorator
def view(request):
    pass
```

A database/decorator combination will be stronger but may involve modifying the [sessions model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#extending-database-backed-session-engines).

You will need to enable sessions as outlined here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#enabling-sessions

Use the decorator on all the views that require it.

I hope this information helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I will research it.